# Decode video frame encoded by Python to display in Node based webapp

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, opencv

I use Python 3 and OpenCV to read video and send the frames to a Node.js based web page via socket.

Let's imagine something like this:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    send(frame)
```

In the `send()` function, before actually sending, I pass the frame into a `normalize()` function to convert it to deliverable format for socket IO. The `normalize()` looks like below:

```
def normalize(frame):
    d = frame.flatten()
    s = d.tostring()
    b = b64encode(s)
    return b.decode('ascii')
```

The data was sent as well. In Node.js app, I receive something as below:

[image: Encoded image data]

How I can convert this encoded string to normal video, or even image?

Thanks.

Comment: The better approach would be to send encoded bytes instead of raw data. Use `cv2.imencode` to encoded frame on the client side and use `cv2.imdecode` to decode it on server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To encode an image, use [`cv2.imencode()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imencode). Then you can write that buffer into a base 64 string, and then display that directly with HTML or whatever you want to do with it.

Here's a basic example. First, the Python:

```
import cv2
import base64

def encode_img(img):
    """Encodes an image as a png and encodes to base 64 for display."""
    success, encoded_img = cv2.imencode('.png', img)
    if success:
        return base64.b64encode(encoded_img).decode()
    raise ValueError("unable to encode image")
```

That will give you the encoded image in base 64. The string that this returns can be displayed directly with HTML by using the string as the `src` of an image if you prepend `data:image/png;base64,` to it.

So for example...

```
import numpy as np
img = np.uint8(255 * np.random.rand(50, 50))
encoded_img = encode_img(img)
b64_src = 'data:image/png;base64,'
img_src = b64_src + encoded_img
```

With this random image my `img_src` becomes:

```
'data:image/png;base64,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'
```

Then in a simple HTML file, use this as the image tag's source:

```
<html>
<body>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
</body>
</html>
```

You should be able to see the image.

You can also save these directly as images on your node server with this format. You can use [`fs.writeFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) in for e.g. to write this b64 string directly to an image file, by specifying an options object with `{encoding: 'base64'}`. For example, from [this tutorial](http://www.codeblocq.com/2016/04/Convert-a-base64-string-to-a-file-in-Node/):

```
import fs from 'fs';
fs.writeFile('image.png', base64Image, {encoding: 'base64'}, function(err) {
    console.log('File created');
});
```

Of course if you're using other libraries in node to play with the images, you'll need to use some function from that library to decode the images. Probably not too hard to exchange from b64 to bytes, but you'll need to decode those bytes into an image from whatever libs you're using server-side.

Comment: thank you so much. That's exactly what I need to get it works. Everything is cool now.